# "==" not doing what i think it should do in Python

Tags: python, comparison

In a script im working on I do the following:

```
data["serial"] = md5.new(json.dumps(data["data"])).hexdigest()
...
...
lst = serialFile.readlines()
    if(len(lst) > 0):
        lastLine = lst[len(lst) - 1]     
...
...
print "lLn : " , lastLine
print "md5 : " , str(data["serial"])
if lastLine == data["serial"]:
```

I can verify that when I print out lLn and md5 they are the same. I feel like i should be tripping the logic statement ... but i do not ...

Also i have tried using :

```
if lastLine == str(data["serial"]):
```

I am still fairly new to Python ... what am i missing here ?

Comment: Probably there is a newline character at the end of `lastLine`.  Try printing `repr(lastLine)` and `repr(data["serial"])`.

Comment: lLn :  e1a9502f3fcd6ec352bb10a1fd8153dd

md5 :  'e1a9502f3fcd6ec352bb10a1fd8153dd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `readlines()` is done on an open file handle, it will read the entire stream out into a list of lines, with lines including the carriage return and newline characters.  You want to call `rstrip()` on the lines to remove all the extra newline and carriage return characters that might be present.  If you also have other whitespace characters at the end that you want to remove you would want to call `rstrip('\r\n')` instead.

Another hint: you don't need to find the length of the list to get the last element, you can simply do `lst[-1]` in your case.

Putting it all together, you would do something like

```
lst = serialFile.readlines()
    if(len(lst) > 0):
        lastLine = lst[-1].rstrip('\r\n')
```

Comment: Platform lineseparators (including `\r\n`) are translated to `\n`, you only need to strip that one character.